# URL redirection for this scenario using cloudflare

Tags: url-rewriting, subdomain, redirect, cdn, cloudflare

I have a website and I connected it to cloudflare CDN.

In there users can post articles. And some selected articles are publiched on our FB page.

two days ago we decided to move our content to subdomain.

So now what ever the content avaliable at test.lk will be avaliable only at forum.test.lk

So in our FB pages we have URLS from our previous one

eg

```
http://test.lk/forum/thread/37/test
```

So now I want to rewrite this URL like this

```
http://forum.test.lk/forum/thread/37/test
```

So how to do this in cloudflare.

Here is cloudflare URL.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-perform-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-CloudFlare-

I used this pattern

```
*.test.lk/+*
```

And targeted URL to

```
http://forum.test.lk$1
```

This works. But if user searched for

```
 http://test.lk/forum/thread/37/test
```

It will redirect to

```
 http://forum.test.lk
```

Not to the specific URL.

SO I am confuse. Can somebody please help me in here.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you are testing, use redirection with a status code 302, so that browser caching will not affect your results.
2. In your pattern, you have 2 occurrences of `*`, and you are only referring to the `$1` (first one) in your redirection.

Update your pattern to:

```
test.lk/*                    (or better yet, to 'test.lk/forum/* )
```

and redirect them to:

```
https://forum.test.lk/$1     (alternatively to 'https://forum.test.lk/forum/$1 )
```

Please notice that I've redirected them to `https` instead of *`http`* as CloudFlare provides a free SSL certificate for wildcard subdomain support. And you should [always prefer HTTPS connection](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/258) for your users.